# Micromax A25 How To Root

Tags: rooting

I've tried several ways to root my Micromax A25. In every case, SP Tool displayed "Partition Size Change" error.

Did anyone yet root successfully?

PS: My A25 firmware version A25_0201_V0409

Comment: Please see the question [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) and look for A25 under Micromax. I've just added an entry in that question after a quick Google search. Please comment if there are any issues.

Comment: @Narayanan please don't link from the index to other sites. It's intended as *internal* index, so rather put your answer here (the link including an excerpt) and then link to this question. Remember, link-only answers are no answers, as the linked page might become unavailable :) Thanks!

Comment: I re-routed the link from the [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575) to point here. For a reference, [this is the link @Narayanan posted](http://www.droidkube.com/how-to-root-and-install-clockworkmod-recovery-on-micromax-smarty-a25/). // To the close-voter: Please check the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) -- this is no duplicate. Our policy is: one "how-to-root" question per device, hence the "index".

Comment: As I've said, I tried different ways, each time I got partition size changed error. Just check the error message: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15625012/a25error.jpg

I've tried automatically and manually installing driver. DA All was disabled, SP tool was run in admin mode. At the end of the day, same result always.


Same for CWM recovery tools also. So finally I failed to root my phone.

Comment: All I could find as of now is: `If you are getting the wrong partition size error that must be because your phone is using different start and end regions for the NAND partitions.

Unfortunately, you must find the correct scatter file for your phone or else you will not be able to flash your phone.` - from [this forum](http://bm-smartphone-reviews.blogspot.in/2011/10/mt65x3-flashing-tutorial.html)

Comment: After trying this, my Phone was bricked. Then I've flashed with stock firmware. And after that I was able to root the phone and install CWM successfully.

And I noticed that, invalid IMEI message was shown. So I've used IMEI writer tool. Now invalid IMEI message was gone and no-service message is there. I've tried to reset/wipe data etc but no luck.

Any suggestion?